# Combine bash variable and parameter expansion on same command

Tags: bash

In a bash shell I tried the following 2 commands producing different effects:

```
$ a=`echo UPDATED` echo ${a:-DEFAULT}
DEFAULT

$ a=`echo UPDATED`; echo ${a:-DEFAULT}
UPDATED
```

Isn't possible to achive the result in one command (first case) ? And if not, why?

Some quotes from the man:

> A  simple  command is a sequence of optional variable assignments
>   followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by
>   a control operator.
>
> Expansion  is  performed on the command line after it has been split into words.

For clarity, the real wold case involves providing a binary to be executed by an **event handler**. The binary path is got from a configuration file, falling back to default if not defined in the configuration file.

Something closer to real case is this snippet, that is called by event handler:

```
a=`getConfigVariable "myExec"` ${a:-/opt/bin/default}
```

Where getConfigVariable "myExec" returns the configuration variable "myExec", or an empty string if it is not defined. For example:

```
$ getConfigVariable "myExec"
/opt/bin/updated
```

Comment: Why not just `a='UPDATED'` in both commands ?

Comment: During expansion the variable assignment is probably not done yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell parses the command line before executing any of it.

In other words, `${a:-DEFAULT}` is evaluated before `a=UPDATED` is assigned.

(Notice also how this rearticulation of the assignment avoids the [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).)

[Chapter 3.5 of the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) has a detailed account of in which order a command line gets parsed. You will notice that parameter expansion is near the beginning, after tilde and brace expansion.

Comment: OK I did a RTFM and in section 3.7.1 it is clear that variable assignment is evaluated just before command execution, while parameter expansion is evaluated earlier. Clause 1.The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later processing, Clause 2 The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded, and finaly Clause 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes .. expansions. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

Comment: And by the way I was reading the "man bash" manual (which has the afforemention explanation under the title "SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION", which I missed) , but this online gnu reference is more readable.

Comment: So this explains why even the simplest form a='UPDATED' echo $a, outputs an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
a=$(echo UPDATED) bash -c 'echo "${a:-DEFAULT}"'

UPDATED
```

`bash -c` will fork a new sub-shell that has inline value of `a` available.

Note that `a=$(echo UPDATED)` is meaningless unless you have some other command substitution there. It can be shortened to:

```
a='UPDATED' bash -c 'echo "${a:-DEFAULT}"'
```

Comment: Running the assignment as a separate command is hugely more efficient than spawning a new shell to run the `echo`!

Comment: OP can clarify further but I suspect OP is trying to avoid setting an env variable in current shell.

Comment: This is indeed an answer achieving the result in one command (i.e. no semicolon), but I would agree with @tripleee that the overhead of spawning a new shell would be bigger than the alternative of two commands. Also A new quoting level is introduced making the snippet less readable. The requirement of one command is more a preference and curiosity since I tried the 2 command example and it works (As I clarified in the answer, this snipped is called by an event handler). Thank you in any case.